# What does 'score' mean in scikit-learn's cross_val_score? Does it mean accuracy?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am new to machine learning, and am using k-fold cross validation on my model. I am using [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html).

The documentation states that `cross_val_score` returns an array of "scores." Is score the same as accuracy? I can't really find an answer to this online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "score" used in `cross_val_score` can be specified by the `scoring` argument to the function. From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score) (same link as in the question):

> scoring : string, callable or None, optional, default: None A string
>   (see model evaluation documentation) or a scorer callable object /
>   function with signature scorer(estimator, X, y) which should return
>   only a single value.
>
> Similar to cross_validate but only a single metric is permitted.
>
> If None, the estimator’s default scorer (if available) is used.

So, you *can* pass accuracy as a score, but if you don't specify any specific score, the estimator's default will be used. If I'm not mistaken, the estimator's default is usually just its loss function. By the fact you're discussing accuracy, I'm assuming you're dealing with a classification problem, where the loss is the cross-entropy... so, this is what you're probably seeing.

You can verify this by calculating the loss and comparing to your score.

Comment: The is so much for this quick and clear answer. Perfect!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer answered your question, please mark it as "accepted" (with the little green "V" mark). If you don't know how to, please visit the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Also, as you're studying machine learning, you'll encounter programming questions (like this one) that fit here in Stack Overflow, but also statistics/machine learning questions (things like "should I perform this transformation before fitting my model?"), which fit in our fellow site Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: There is a list of scorers [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) .